# combining two lists in jython

Tags: python, list, jython

I am trying to write a function in jython that will combine the elements from two different lists in order to create one word.

For example:

the function takes two lists both names as a and b

if a is `["eat", "pray", "love"]`
and b is `["er", "ing", "d"]`
and you typed in makeWord(a,b)
it would return with:

```
["eater", "praying", "loved"]
```

so far I have:

```
def makeWords(a,b):
     a = []
    list1 = a
    b = []
    list2 = b
    new_list = []
    for word in list1:
        new_list.append((list1[i] + list2[i]))
    return new_list
```

but i know i am obviously doing at least a few things wrong. any help would greatly be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(list1, list2))
```

Or arguably more readable:

```
map(''.join, zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: The lambda isn't needed, even: `map(''.join, zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: @Hamish: Yep, I was editing that in even as you commented ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This should work as well:

```
>>> a = ["eat", "pray", "love"]
>>> b = ["er", "ing", "d"]
>>> [start + end for start, end in zip(a, b)]
['eater', 'praying', 'loved']
```

For Joel Cornett, the `timeit` code:

```
import timeit

a = '''
a = ["eat", "pray", "love"]
b = ["er", "ing", "d"]
[start + end for start, end in zip(a, b)]
'''

b = '''
a = ["eat", "pray", "love"]
b = ["er", "ing", "d"]
map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(a, b))
'''

c = '''
a = ["eat", "pray", "love"]
b = ["er", "ing", "d"]
map(''.join, zip(a, b))
'''

timeit.Timer(a).timeit(number=1000000)
timeit.Timer(b).timeit(number=1000000)
timeit.Timer(c).timeit(number=1000000)
```

Comment: `"".join()` may be faster than string concatenation in the interpreter.

Comment: Oddly, no. `1000000` iterations of this code took `1.1707520484924316` seconds while the `''.join(x)` took `2.0265748500823975` seconds.

Comment: I tested all three chunks and the string concatenation turned out to be the fastest.